# Ruby base class call child class like in abstract classes

Tags: ruby, oop, inheritance

In Java, I am used to writing an abstract class that does some setup work and then delegates to the concrete class like this:

```java
public abstract class Base {
    public void process() {
        // do some setup
        //...

        // then call the concrete class
        doRealProcessing();
    }
     
    protected abstract void doRealProcessing();
}

public class Child extends Base {
    @Override
    protected void doRealProcessing() {
        // do the real processing
    } 
}
```

I am having a hard time doing this in Ruby because I don't have abstract classes or methods. I also read that "you aren't supposed to **need** abstract classes or methods in Ruby and that I should stop trying to write Java in Ruby".

I would love to know what is the right way to implement the equivalence in Ruby?

Comment: Why can't you implement it just like that, except that you don't need the abstract function in the base class??? (Although you may want to throw an exception to indicate subclasses are missing an implementation.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to dynamically typed languages!  You were probably nervous about just defining some function that wasn't declared anywhere.  Don't be worried.  It is very easy:

```
class Base
  def process
     # ...
     real_processing
  end

  def real_processing    # This method is optional!
    raise "real_processing not implemented in #{self.class.name}"
  end
end

class Child < Base
   def real_processing
     # ...
   end
end

b = Child.new
b.process
```

**EDIT:** Here's another option for you which avoids the need to have two different method names:

```
class Base
  def process
    # ...
  end
end

class Child < Base
  def process
    # ...
    super   # calls the process method defined above in Base
    # ...
  end
end
```

Comment: That's too easy... I really need to stop using Java in my day job and use dynamic languages for everything. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do the template pattern in Ruby:

```
class Template
  def template_method
    perform_step1
    perform_step2
    #do some extra work
  end

  def perform_step1
    raise "must be implemented by a class"
  end

  def perform_step2
    raise "must be implemented by a class"
  end
end

class Implementation < Template
  def perform_step1
    #implementation goes here
  end

  def perform_step2
    #implementation goes here
  end
end
```

http://andymaleh.blogspot.com/2008/04/template-method-design-pattern-in-ruby.html

Answer (score 0):

You don't see much of this in Ruby for this use case, because the pattern

- do some household setup ( make a connection to a resource for
  instance)
- do something real with it
- teardown household job (f.i. close connection)

is baked into ordinary methods:

```
# pseudocode:
def a_method(an_argument)
  # do some setup with an_argument
  yield(a_result)
  # do some teardown
end

# use like:
a_method(the_argument){|the_result| puts "real processing with #{the_result}"}
```